# Date not properly parsed in Bash

Tags: bash, date, unix

I'm trying to get the date to work properly. The time is 5 pm (1700 hours) now i.e. evening but it always says morning. Here's my code

```
currenthour="$(date "+ %-H")"
echo $currenthour
if [ $currenthour -gt '12' ] && [ $currenthour -lt '16' ]; then
   currenttimeofday="Afternoon"
elif [ $currenthour -gt '16' ] && [ $currenthour -lt '1' ]; then
   currenttimeofday="Evening"
 else
   currenttimeofday="Morning"
fi
echo $currenttimeofday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space between the plus and the percentage symbol, your variable then will be used properly in the condition.

Comment: I removed the space but still it doesn't solve the problem. The echo $currenthour works perfectly even with the space so i'm guessing there is something wrong in the condition.!!

Comment: The second condition should have an OR (||) since it's covering two spaces, anything that is greater than 16 and anything that is lower than 1.

Comment: oh didn't notice that. Thanks a lot. problem fixed

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin: `echo $currenthour` is not a reliable way to see what's in the currenthour variable. When a variable is expanded, it's then subject to word splitting and wildcard expansion -- and word splitting has the side effect of removing leading and trailing spaces. To get a better idea what's actually in the variable, use `echo "'$currenthour'"` -- the double-quotes prevent word splitting and wildcard expansion, and the single-quotes print along with the variable so you can see where it starts and ends.